# Does BigQuery limits number of select queries to 1000 per day?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery quotas [says](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#jobs):

> Maximum number of queued interactive queries  1,000 queries   Your project can queue up to 1,000 interactive queries. Additional interactive queries that exceed this limit return a quota error.

and that any [query on demand is interactive query job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries)

> By default, BigQuery runs your queries as interactive query jobs, which are run as soon as possible

Does this mean that maximum number of SELECT queries could be performed in one project is 1000 per day (as Google BigQuery resets limits once a day)?

Comment: No. [This quota is for interactive queries. You can run batch queries as well. Actually, after the limit for interactive queries is reached, all queries default to batch only](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries).

Comment: @narendra-choudhary but every SELECT is interactive query?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery runs interactive (on-demand) query jobs by default where queries return results quickly. It counts to your **concurrent rate limit** and **your daily limit**.

The 1000 queries per day quota is for queued interactive queries only and does not necessarily mean that you can only perform 1,000 **SELECT** queries per day. The `SELECT` statement is used to retrieve data from one or more tables in a dataset. By default, when you submit a SELECT query, it is treated as an interactive query, but not every SELECT query is an interactive query.

Also, the daily query size limit is **unlimited**:

> By default, there is no daily query size limit. However, you can set limits on the amount of data users can query by creating custom quotas to control query usage per day or query usage per day per user.

However, you can still [request a quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#requesting_a_quota_increase).